# Dynamic ng-table with fixed header

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ngtable

I'm trying to get this ng-table to play nice: http://jsfiddle.net/orarbel/ADukg/8102/

This is how I get the header to be fixed:

```
thead, tbody {
   display: block;
}
```

The problem is the header width and and body width are not the same, the scrolling get broken, and I can't get the CSS right.

I'm basically trying to figure out how to style this table so that the header is fixed and if there is a horizontal overflow the header and body would still be aligned.

Suggestions?

Comment: Missing some data to test in your JSFiddle. $data is not defined. Could you give some $data in?